# How to fix address clipping or add an offset (in appsetting)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, razor-pages

For example, I have a login (get and post) controller that each returns a `return actionresult view()` in the view, I have a sketch of textboxes and buttons, all this is wrapped in `html.beginform(account, login)`.

The question is as follows: how to make it so that for example in the url I added url: `host/.../.../account/login`.

How to make these same points in the address bar. For when deploying on the server - I have a problem in the form of eating the address bar and instead of the correct address in the form of `host/.../.../account/login`.

When you click on the submit button, the address bar is truncated to `host/account/login`.

Or how add an offset?

Comment: `Html.BeginForm` provides you with the best addressing mode. Why change it?

Comment: because it cut my url in server from host/.../.../acc/log to host/acc/log

Comment: Have you used this method? `<form action="host/.../.../account/login" method="post">`

Comment: me forbidden write full url, because app needs be is flexibility. And i resolve this